Volatile alternative to PBS that is compatible with LCMS analysis for cell lysis experiment
I have two chemical compounds that I put on cells, to see if they can diffuse into the cytosol. The compounds are similar in structure, but contain a key modification that alter the polarity completely. After the cells are incubated, they are washed with PBS several times to remove excess compound. PBS is used not to rupture the cells pre maturely. The goal here is just to see compound that actually went into the cell, not something that was there from the beginning. The final sample contains the lysate after protein precipitation with 2 parts methanol and 1 part PBS.
PBS however contains of Sodium, Potassium, Phosphate and Hydrogen phosphate and Chloride ions which are all non volatile and therefore may cause problems with LCMS detection or ion suppression in some cases. Therefore I am  wondering if it could replaced by ammonium formate at 154 mM concentration at pH 7.4? For washing and injection steps? (NH4Fa is also the buffer in the LCMS run) Could this be used as a substitute or cant PBS be replaced?
